# how to properly use a key value database like mongo db

Tags: mongodb, database-design, couchdb, non-relational-database, database

I have heard that a lot of big companies using non-relational databases like mongo db. I would like to know how and why people use them on an industrial scale. I am working to design an ebay like project. I would like to figure out what would work best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, MongoDB is not a key-value store, it is  document store.
Industry scale sites use NoSQL for parts of their stack to address a specific problem that a NoSQL data-store solves better than relational databases for example Redis is optimized for performance under real-time data workloads and hence it is better fit for storing real-time data than MySQL. Relational databases are still heavily used as main data-stores.

The bottom-line is relational databases are fine in most cases. Use other technologies when you want to address relational database shortcomings and use tools specific to the problem. Don't preoptimize. Tackle issues as they come.

Comment: what do you mean by a document store? what kind of documents?

Comment: @CoderKK Mongodb stores data in documents(Binary JSON). See http://www.slideshare.net/mdirolf/inside-mongodb-the-internals-of-an-opensource-database